# Is it possible for Reinforced.Typings to generate files in the same location as the corresponding C# model?

Tags: c#, .net, reinforced-typings

We are working on a .net core project with React components, and we are using C# models and TS types to describe component proptypes. We keep the C# model in the components folder. We would prefer to keep the TS file in the same folder.

Is it possible for Reinforced.Typings to generate files in the same location as the corresponding C# model?

Comment: Please no. They shouldn't even be in the same project in a nice world.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`RtDivideTypesAmongFiles`](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/wiki/Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml#-rtdividetypesamongfiles-boolean) to `True` within Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml and then use [`[TsFile]`](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/wiki/Configuration-attributes#-tsfile-not-required) attribute or [`.ExportTo`](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/wiki/Fluent-configuration#interface) fluent methods to specify any place where you want your files to be placed to. This functionality requires from you to have full path to target file.

Please find a way to obtain CLR type's source code location by yourself. You can search in the direction of [StackFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe?view=netcore-3.1) class and its methods.